# File upload in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

i needed a file upload feature in my project built on ASP.NET 3.5 and C#. I followed the following link to do so.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246.
I created a folder named Data and followed everything as stated in the link.But my files didnt get uploaded in that folder named Data.What should i do to upload a file?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You should show us some code/configuration, otherwise we would figure that you followed everything exactly from the example - which should work.  Also, like others said, post any errors too.

Answer (score 1):

Any exception is thrown? Do you give the permission to the account you program run under? What's size of your file upload? Try a small one first, such as 1K file. ASP.NET has a size limit, and you can change the limit in the config file.

Comment: no exception is thrown. For the permission of folder named Data ,i went to properties of the Data folder and in 'the Select Users or Groups dialog box' i didnt find ASPNET account as stated in the example shown in link, so i gave the permission to everyone and i tried uploading small size file of 1k.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 class Proizvod {
            public string ceo_red, ime, proizvodjac, ram, tip, kamera,slika, ekran,sifra, cena;
            

            public Proizvod(string x) {
                ceo_red = x;
                slika = x.Split(',')[0];
                sifra = x.Split(',')[1];
                ime = x.Split(',')[2];
                proizvodjac = x.Split(',')[3];
                ram = x.Split(',')[4];
                tip = x.Split(',')[5];
                kamera = x.Split(',')[6];
                ekran = x.Split(',')[7];
                cena = x.Split(',')[8];
            }
        
        }
        List<Proizvod> proizvodi = new List<Proizvod>();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"F:\dji\A8\A8\TextFile1.txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                proizvodi.Add(new Proizvod(sr.ReadLine()));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < proizvodi.Count; i++)
            {
                bool isti = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < DropDownList1.Items.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (proizvodi[i].proizvodjac == DropDownList1.Items[j].Text) isti = true;
                }
                if (!isti) DropDownList1.Items.Add(proizvodi[i].proizvodjac);

                isti = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < DropDownList2.Items.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (proizvodi[i].ram == DropDownList2.Items[j].Text) isti = true;
                }
                if (!isti) DropDownList2.Items.Add(proizvodi[i].ram);

                isti = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < DropDownList3.Items.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (proizvodi[i].tip == DropDownList3.Items[j].Text) isti = true;
                }
                if (!isti) DropDownList3.Items.Add(proizvodi[i].tip);

                isti = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < DropDownList4.Items.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (proizvodi[i].kamera == DropDownList4.Items[j].Text) isti = true;
                }
                if (!isti) DropDownList4.Items.Add(proizvodi[i].kamera);

                isti = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < DropDownList5.Items.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (proizvodi[i].ekran == DropDownList5.Items[j].Text) isti = true;
                }
                if (!isti) DropDownList5.Items.Add(proizvodi[i].ekran);
            }
            Table1.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Proizvod> trazeni = new List<Proizvod>();
            for (int i = 0; i < proizvodi.Count; i++)
            {
                if (proizvodi[i].proizvodjac == DropDownList1.Text && proizvodi[i].ram == DropDownList2.Text && proizvodi[i].tip == DropDownList3.Text && proizvodi[i].kamera == DropDownList4.Text && proizvodi[i].ekran == DropDownList5.Text)
                {
                    
                    trazeni.Add(proizvodi[i]);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < trazeni.Count; i++)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                    
                    tc.Text = trazeni[i].ceo_red.Split(',')[j];
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                }
                Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
            Table1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```